# Java 11 Apache HTTPClient SSL certificate authentication not working

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using modified version below code for SSL client certificate authentication. It worked in JDK 8, recently I changed to JDK 11, now with same code authentication is failing. If I switch to JDK 8 it works.
Any changes in JDK 11 to handle the SSL client certificate authentication? Any tips to make this code work JDK will be helpful.

```
package org.example.test;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.config.Registry;
import org.apache.http.config.RegistryBuilder;
import org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.socket.ConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContexts;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

/**
 * Demonstrate connecting to a server secured with client-side SSL certificates.
 */
public class ConnectIT {

    /**
     * Path to your client-side SSL certificate in the PKCS12 format, as generated by OpenSSL.
     */
    final String KEY_STORE_PATH = "/path/to/pkcs12file.p12";

    /**
     * PKCS12 file passphrase.
     */
    final String KEY_STORE_PASSWORD = "correct horse battery staple";

    /**
     * URL to connect to. That is, a server for which the above certificate is required.
     */
    final String URL = "https://secure.example.org";

    @Test
    public void sslConnect() throws KeyStoreException, IOException, CertificateException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException {

        // Load the key store, containing the client-side certificate.
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        InputStream keyStoreInput = new FileInputStream(KEY_STORE_PATH);
        keyStore.load(keyStoreInput, KEY_STORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        System.out.println("Key store has " + keyStore.size() + " keys");

        // Create an SSL context with our private key store.
        // We are only loading the key-material here, but if your server uses a self-signed certificate,
        // you will need to load the trust-material (a JKS key-store containing the server's public SSL
        // certificate) as well.
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, KEY_STORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray())
                .useTLS()
                .build();

        // Prepare the HTTPClient.
        HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                sslContext, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        builder.setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionFactory);
        Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                .register("https", sslConnectionFactory)
                .register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory())
                .build();
        HttpClientConnectionManager ccm = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);
        builder.setConnectionManager(ccm);

        // Perform a sample HTTP request.
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = builder.build()) {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
            try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget)) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                if (entity != null) {
                    System.out.println("Response content length: " + entity.getContentLength());
                    System.out.printf(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
                }
                EntityUtils.consume(entity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What part of it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JRE 11 is not a problem but the `TLSv1.3` it uses by default is. Apache HttpClient 5.0 has been tested for compatibility with JRE 11 `TLSv1.3` but HttpClient 4.5 has not. For now just force the use of `TLSv1.2` and the problem *should* go away.

Comment: let me try this, I am using HttpClient 4.5,  httpclient 5.0 still in beta